# Regex pattern to match words inbetween the first and last token with the first word being constant

Tags: java, regex, string

I have tried a lot of approaches to match a certain String, but my efforts have proven abortive.

I need a pattern to match all the words in a string. The first word must be
 present before it matches the remaining words. Also, the words following the 
first word should have a comma, except the last word.

**Example**

```
String str = "var a, n,d, e, g, h"
```

In this example, `var` must be present before the pattern matches the remaining characters`(a, n,d, e, g, h)`. The characters can be more than the one in the example, it can be`(a, n, d, e, g, h, k, l,...)`.

**EDITED**

I tried something like this

```
String p = "((\\w+),[|\\s+]?)";
```

and matched the first group. It only shows `a, n, d, e, g` with the exception of `h`

Comment: What did you try and what you need? you need to print 'var' you mean?

Comment: Post your best effort, and explain why it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match your words in a capturing group:

```
(?:\bvar\b|\G)\s*(\w+)(?:,|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ6tX6/1)

`(?:\bvar\b|\G)` matches `var` OR `\G` that asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

`(?:,|$)` will match a comma or end of string after capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA7dB5/1)

```
^var\s+(\w+,\s*)*\w+$
```